# Power supply for guitar pedals

Tags: electric-guitar, effects-pedal

I'm fairly new to guitar pedals. I tried to buy on ebay used guitar pedals, but none of them are selling with power supply. Why is that so?

Comment: You may want to look into a "daisy chain" power supply, that can power multiple pedals through one electrical socket slot.  The one I use is called 1 Spot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mainly for two reasons - they mostly can work with batteries, they are originally not sold with power supplies. A third reason may be that the original owner will still have other pedals, so will retain the psu for his own use. If sold to another country, the psu may not have the suitable plug or even input voltage.

Comment: Good point! I didn't know that they aren't sold originally with power supply! Everyday I learn something new :-)

Answer (score 3):

*To expand on the point Tim made about the fact that they are originally not sold with power supplies:*

When using simple 'stompbox'-type pedals, guitarists typically use a number of pedals chained together.

Rather than have a separate mains power supply for each pedal, it's more convenient to have a single high-quality power supply powering all the pedals - e.g. the Pedal Power 2 plus in this picture:

[image: http://proaudiodvds.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Guitar-Pedalboard-Power-All-Supply.jpg]

If you're powering pedals in this way, you wouldn't want the prices of the pedals you are buying to be inflated by the inclusion of another power supply you wouldn't need.

Comment: Thanks @topo morto. That was a good setup from the photo you uploaded! As I understood, there is only "one" guitar input in this pedal chaining? Right? So that user can only step/switch to effect he wants.

Comment: @Blackcoat77 I am not sure how many inputs there are. The effects will be usable in combination, not just one at a time.

Comment: In addition to the space-saving convenience (over "wall warts") and possibly flexible voltage ratings, another reason for power supplies as pictured above is the "isolation" that they can provide via each transformer "leg". This isolation avoids "ground loops" which create undesirable signal noise.

Comment: Hey is that a loooper? I wasn't sure they still made those. Looks like a nice one.

Comment: Looper is an overused term these days. Yes, it appears to be a multiple-loop switch. I have a GigRig QM8 which probably behaves similarly. It can be confusing that the term "looper" is also used to describe musical memory/replay devices.